# How to match oculus user with facebook user

Tags: facebook, authentication, oculus, oculusquest

We're developing a VR game for oculus quest 2. We implemented a file export function to allow the user to export their work to our web server. It works great.

We let users log in to our app with their Oculus IDs (which is their Facebook IDs) so they don't have to create a new user etc.

However, the user has to log in to our web site using their FB id to access their files, and here we have a problem:

We could find no way to match the ID that facebook login for web returns and the ID that oculus entitlement check returns.

So we have a user who logs in with the same facebook user to two different platforms, which gives us different user ID s and different user names.

Anybody has any idea on how to reconcile these two?

Comment: I have an idea, which will just force you to a brick wall.... Make the user actually use facebook login from the app, and you can get his email/id/access token, but the brickwall is - logging into facebook using either `facebook-login:11.2.0` up to `facebook-sdk:12.3.0` just loads in the browser indefinitely.

Comment: Any solution to this problem yet? Im having same issue